# SQL find all rows with assigned values

Tags: sql, sql-server

MSSQL: i have this example data:

```
NAME    AValue   BValue
A       1        11
B       1        11
C       2        11
D       2        21
E       3        21
F       3        21
G       4        31
H       4        31
I       5        41
J       5        NULL
...
```

I am looking for algorhitm which looks for all the Names closed by values by different seed (AValue and Bvalue, in this case seed is given by 2 for AValue and by 3 for Bvalue, but this can be skipped and given later and so on, not only looking for smallest multiple). In this case output should be 1,2,3,4,11,21,31 as a first group/result. Then all the Names with these values can be updated etc.

I need to find out all the Names in "closed circle" of values by different seed.

EDIT:
(try of simplier example)

Imagine that you have list of names. Each name is given two numbers. In most cases these numbers are given by some seed (in this example AValue is given twice, BValue three times) but some numbers can be skipped, so you cannot just count smallest multiple of these different seeds(in this case it would be 2x3, ever 6 names you have closed group where no Name contains AValue or BValue from next/different group). For example Name A have 1 and 11. 1 is given for A and B, 11 for A, B, C. These Names have 1,2,11,21. So you check for 2 and 21 and then you get E and F in addition and then the loop of checking should continue, but as long as no more Names are contained there should be output 1,2,3,11,21. "Closed circle"

Comment: I really cannot follow your explanation.  Can you simplify it?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Did you really understand what he wants to achieve? hh

Comment: Can you also add your current query attempt?

Comment: Honestly, there is no attempt so far. I am thinking about some while loop checking from A to all B values and vice versa until u get all of the Names... so far i am solving this by sorting by A and B then comparing visually.